# Multiple "typical characteristic" charts in FET datasheet

Tags: datasheet, fet, device-characteristics

Looking at following datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N5457-D.PDF

I'm puzzled as to why there are multiple "typical characteristic " (pairs of) charts. As far as my understanding goes, FETs are voltage controlled devices so why do we have multiple (and contradictory) values of drain current for given drain-source voltage and gate voltage? (figures 2, 4 and 6).

Comment: Note that each graph is for a different Vgs(off) value (aka pinch-off voltage), thus these graphs show the likely variation between devices from different batches.

Comment: Wow, the differences are quite big!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the part has a large variation in the gate-source cutoff voltage (see spec table), they have provided curves for 3 "typical" parts with different cutoff voltages.

Figure 4 may be the most typical, but if they only provided this curve, it could be misleading to the user.